# Why are the text-align buttons not appearing in my CK Editor in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, ckeditor, wysiwyg

Essentially, I've been back and forth through settings and configuration for using the CK Editor as well as re-installing it but for whatever reason the text-align buttons for this WYSIWYG editor are not showing up despite the fact they appear to be configured to do so.

I'm using Drupal 7.19 and CK Editor 7.x-1.12. For clarification, this is the CK Editor as stand-alone project, not a part of the WYSIWYG project.

Also to be clear, this is not a problem of the buttons not working or text-align properties being stripped out, **the buttons are simply not there**. Which is a problem for ease of use for my end-users.

Why would this be happening?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Most likely you have downloaded a standard package which does not include `justify` plugin. Download the full package or add this plugin using [online builder](http://ckeditor.com/builder).

Comment: Thank you, I knew I must be missing something inane.

Answer (score 3):

This is due to the "Limit allowed HTML tags and correct faulty HTML" filter settings. As outlined in this issue, you must explicitly allow those classes on the p tag https://www.drupal.org/node/2649546

```
<p class="text-align-left text-align-center text-align-right text-align-justify">
```

Also this is for Drupal 8